# Unicode Characters in HTTP post from body not working

Tags: c#, http-post, unicode-string

I am trying to post a string which contains a Unicode nDash character (`–`) using a WebClient call:

```js
{
    "data": "This is a test – string"
}
```

When I try to post, the WebClient is receiving null.

This is my WebClient call:

```cs
using (IDisposable context = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) {
    var data = false;
    using (var client = new WebClientCall()) {
        client.BaseAddress = "https://BaseAddress"
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageContents);
        var json = client.UploadString($"api/data", "POST", dataString);

        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });

        return data;
    }
}

private class WebClientCall : WebClient {
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null) {
            webRequest.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
            webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        return (WebRequest)webRequest;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me send non-ASCII characters in a WebClient call?

Comment: What do you mean the *WebClient* is receiving null?  You mean `client.UploadString()` is returning a null `string`? What are you *expecting* it to return? Are you sure the problem is not on the server side? What does the underlying HTTP request and response look like? Maybe the server is not able to process your JSON and fails. Also, try setting the `WebClient.Encoding` property to `Encoding.UTF8`. `WebClient.Encoding` defaults to `Encoding.Default`, which may lose Unicode characters. `application/json` is usually expected to be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Setting WebClient.Encoding to Encoding.UTF8 worked thank you